Modeling ultrafine particles with CAMx
As far as I know CAMx (COMPREHENSIVE AIR QUALITY MODEL WITH EXTENSIONS) handles PM10 and PM2.5 aerosols. I would like to ask if there is any implementation in CAMx about ultrafine aerosol (less than 100 nm diameter).

Depending on how you setup the model, you can analyze aerosol size and composition with great detail.  See here:  https://www.camx.com/Files/CAMxUsersGuide_v7.30.pdf
